# Is this compulsory for a Muslim to obey all the government rules in a non-Islamic country

Tags: sharia, sin

By non-Islamic, I mean a country that is not ruled according to Shariah. Not necessarily non-Muslim-majority. For example, my country, Bangladesh, is a Muslim-majority country, but not a Islamic country.

And by rules, of course I mean those rules which do not contradict Shariah. I am sure if a rule contradict shariah, it cannot be obeyed by a Muslim.

---

I believe most countries have an age restriction for marriage. Bangladesh has 18 years for women and 21 years for men. Now, I have seen many people give their daughter to marriage before 18. Perhaps because it is encouraged by the Prophet (S).

Now, Is it farz for a Muslim to obey such a rule? Or it depends on situation and type of the rule.

Comment: Very similar question http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1803/140

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a hadith which says that our Prophet (pbuh) said that we must obey the ruler of the country we reside in unless ofcourse the rule goes against islam:

> the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) said: “It is
>   necessary upon a Muslim to listen to and obey the ruler, as long as
>   one is not ordered to carry out a sin. If he is commanded to commit a
>   sin, then there is no adherence and obedience.” (Sahih al-Bukhari, no.
>   2796 & Sunan Tirmidhi)

[Here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/128453) is a fatwa about this issue, and here is a relevant extract from that fatwa:

> The ruler who does not rule according to the Book of Allaah and the
>   Sunnah of His Messenger should be obeyed in matters that do not
>   involve disobedience towards Allaah and His Messenger