# Cyber Attack on haram website (porn, drugs, etc)

Tags: fiqh, internet

In the name of Allah,

As we know that website that provides porn, drugs, gambling, etc are haram in islam. Can we just attack those website until they're not accessible anymore? I've done few attacks but I stopped since I realized those attacks maybe wrong too.

Comment: Have you ever really stopped them, even if we try we will probably be labelled as people who repress sexual freedom (just a thought you can still go ahead and try your hardest if you wish). I think first we should teach our own people about how they are bad and protect our own people from using them before telling non believers.

Comment: @Loading...both solution will be good (educate believers & non belivers and confront haram industry)

Comment: Would you do cyber attacks on websites or government websites that sells alcohol?

Comment: @Kilise depends on the purpose of the alcohol itself

Comment: Related https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/what-are-counter-arguments-for-those-who-do-not-admit-to-the-laws-of-a-secular-c

Comment: the problem now I live in a country where such websites are forbidden, while at the same time those websites insist to give access to my country, soo...

Answer (score 1):

According to a fatwa from Grand Ayatollah Lotfollah Safi Golpaygani, if a website is purely against Islam and the advice and warning have had no effect, it is necessary to hack it.

[Reference](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa57718)